# "around or about + an amount of time"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

> She's been pregnant [for] *about/around* 5 weeks.

Which one is more preferable and more commonly used in the sentence above?

For me, both are interchangeable. But I can't articulate why. It feels like both can be used along with an amount of time with little difference in meaning.

Based on my research, both can be used *with a number or quantity* with the meaning: ***approximately,*** so there may not be any nuance of meaning. Therefore, I think I am correct they can be used interchangeably and I also suppose there is no considerable difference in register too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! I retagged your question, removing the "prepositions" tag because the consensus has "about/around" pegged as adverbs as opposed to prepositions, see [this discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56313/identify-parts-of-speech) please.

Comment: Also related: [“About” vs. “around”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26666/about-vs-around)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more natural for people to associate "around" with the physical location of something (usually in 2- or 3-D).

People will associate "about" with locations, too, but that is not common.

"About" is applicable to 1-D --- which time is frequently thought of as.

---

### TL;DR:

- "About" is better.
- They both refer to uncertainty.

---

### Why?

When one hears "round", they think "circle" or "sphere".
Circles don't really exist on a number line.
So they don't really exist within time (a 1-D mindset), either.

That's why it sounds weird.

"About", on the other hand, doesn't carry a dimension. This property leads to its fitting application in the time mindset.

Comment: I would consider it perfectly idiomatic to use _around_ in this context, the sense being 'perhaps a little less or a little more than five weeks', as though there were a circle with 'exactly five weeks' as its centre.